# Facebook Instant Articles - CONTENT NOT MATCHED

Tags: php, facebook-instant-articles

I'm trying to publish test article by [Facebook Instant Articles PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-instant-articles-sdk-php):

```
$the_html = '<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" prefix="op: http://media.facebook.com/op#">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta property="op:markup_version" content="v1.0">
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://myarticle">
  <meta property="fb:article_style" content="default">
</head>
<body>
  <article>
    <header>
      <h1> test title</h1>
      <h2> test subtitle </h2>

       <time class="op-published" dateTime="2016-06-20T08:00">June 17th 2016, 8:00 AM</time>
      <time class="op-modified" dateTime="2016-06-20T08:00">June 17th 2016, 8:00 AM</time>

      <p> Test test test </p>
    </header>
  </article>
</body>
</html>';

 $fb = Client::create(
    'APP_ID'
    'APP_SECRET',
    'ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'PAGE_ID',
     true //development env
 );

$instant_article = InstantArticle::create();
$transformer = new Transformer();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($the_html);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$transformer->transform($instant_article, $document);

$fb->importArticle($instant_article, true);
```

I'm getting this message:

> DEBUG - =========================== DEBUG -
>   =========================== DEBUG - context class: Facebook\InstantArticles\Elements\InstantArticle DEBUG - node name:
>   html DEBUG - CONTENT NOT MATCHED:

I was able to publish article by using Instant Articles API in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), but can't make it work with PHP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add file with rules and load it. [File example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ri7tuvxaydd9b9v/simple-rules.json?dl=0).

```
$rules = file_get_contents("instantArticlesModule/simple-rules.json", true);
$transformer = new Transformer();
$transformer->loadRules($rules);
```

Comment: Thank you mate for your help. Spasibo ^^